# git submodule status - How to change the way references are described

Tags: git

In `git submodule status`, all submodules are listed in the format:

`[ ][commit_sha] [relative path] [description of commit with 'git describe']`

For instance:

```sh
$ git submodule status
 f6811d2be995498c162000c27608a0bf4df8d315 submod_1 (tagname-42-gf6811d2)
 beda48ff60e29fc31e2a9472041500f39736039d submod_2 (heads/master)
```

My question is: how to customize the description of commit?

In particular, I would like to pass the `--exact-match` to the underlying `git describe` of commits so that tag names are not used when not exactly matching (but rather branch name if existing!)

Answer (score 1):

You can build whatever you want, it's a a near-oneliner, demo:

```
git config -f .gitmodules --get-regexp path$ \
| while IFS='. ' read x submodule x path; do
    echo $submodule recorded commit is `git rev-parse :$path`
    echo $submodule current commit is `git -C $path describe --all --exact @`
done
```